# xubuntu 14.04 wont recognise my huawei e3372h 4g modem

Tags: xubuntu, usb-modem, huawei, 4g

good morning 
I am trying tu use my huawei e3372h modem on my xubuntu 14.04 but it wont work.
xubuntu recognise the modem as an usb flash memory.
i really need some help 
thanks